# how to implement fluent builder with inheritance in java

Tags: java, inheritance, builder, fluent, fluent-interface

## problem

I want to create a class with a fluent builder, both of which can be inherited and extended. Base class should have all the common and mandatory fields, children should have different optional fields

simple example below (best, simplistic usecase I could come up with ;p)

```
base: Animal
    name
    age

    static Builder


impl: Snake extends Animal
    length

    static Builder extends Animal.Builder


impl: Spider extends Animal
    numberOfLegs

    static Builder extends Animal.Builder
```

and I'd like to use it in one of those ways (most preferred one is the first one):

```
Spider elvis = Spider.name("elvis").age(1).numberOfLegs(8).build();
Spider elvis = Spider.builder().name("elvis").age(1).numberOfLegs(8).build();
Spider elvis = new Spider.Builder().name("elvis").age(1).numberOfLegs(8).build();
```

## what I want to achieve is

- user of this builder will have to provide some minimal information (so the system can work without problems), otherwise he won't be able to build that object
- all the optional fields can be declared, with no particular order, after mandatory fields are there
- it is possible that I'll need to add some mandatory fields for children, but that can be handled with ease by just changing the first method called in the builder

  - I don't want to have any casts outside those classes (here: in Main), but I don't mind them inside this code (here: in Animal or Spider)

so far I failed and I'd be very grateful if you could please help me find a way out of it :)
or maybe there is just a different approach that I should think about?

## most valuable sources I used

http://blog.crisp.se/2013/10/09/perlundholm/another-builder-pattern-for-java
http://egalluzzo.blogspot.com/2010/06/using-inheritance-with-fluent.html
[Generic fluent Builder in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778148/generic-fluent-builder-in-java)

## work done so far

the code so far can be found below. there are some traces of the things I tried and failed, there are some unused or just weird stuff (best example is IBuildImpl). Those are left to give you an understanding of what I tried, but if you think that this needs moderation - please let me know and I'll clean them up

#### Base

```
package fafafa;

public abstract class Animal<T> {
    String name; //mandatory field, one of many
    Integer age; //mandatory field, one of many

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Animal{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", age='" + age + '\'' +
                '}';
    }


    interface IName {
        IAge name(String name);
    }

    interface IAge {
        IBuild age(Integer age);
    }

    interface IBuild<T extends Animal<T>> {
        T build();
    }


    public abstract static class Builder<T extends Animal<T>, B extends Builder<T, B>>
            implements IName, IAge, IBuild<T> {
        protected T objectBeingBuilt;

        protected abstract B that();
        protected abstract T createEmptyObject();

        Builder(){
            this.objectBeingBuilt = createEmptyObject();
            System.out.println();
        }

        @Override
        public IAge name(String name) {
            objectBeingBuilt.name = name;
            return that();
        }

        @Override
        public IBuild age(Integer age) {
            objectBeingBuilt.age = age;
            return that();
        }

//        @Override
//        public T build() {
//            return objectBeingBuilt;
//        }
    }


}
```

#### Impl

```
package fafafa;

public class Spider extends Animal<Spider> {
    Integer numberOfLegs; //optional field, one of many

    private Spider() {
    }

    public Integer getNumberOfLegs() {
        return numberOfLegs;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Spider{" +
                "numberOfLegs='" + numberOfLegs + '\'' +
                "} " + super.toString();
    }

//    public static Builder<Spider, Builder> name(String name) {
//        return (Builder) new Builder().name(name);
//    }


    interface INumberOfLegs {
        IBuild numberOfLegs(Integer numberOfLegs);
    }

    interface IBuildImpl extends IBuild<Spider>, INumberOfLegs {
        @Override
        Spider build();
    }


    public static class Builder extends Animal.Builder<Spider, Builder> implements IBuildImpl {

        @Override
        protected Builder that() {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        protected Spider createEmptyObject() {
            return new Spider();
        }


        public IBuild numberOfLegs(Integer numberOfLegs) {
            objectBeingBuilt.numberOfLegs = numberOfLegs;
            return that();
        }

        public Spider build() {
            return objectBeingBuilt;
        }
    }
}
```

#### Main

```
package fafafa;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Spider build = new Spider.Builder().name("elvis")
                .age(1)
                .numberOfLegs(8) //cannot resolve method numberOfLegs
                .build();
        System.out.println(build);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of your code is the interface:

```
interface IAge {
    IBuild age(Integer age);
}
```

This will always return the basic `IBuild` interface with no parameter, no matter, if the implementation implements it with some argument. Actually even returning it with the parameter wouldn't extend the builder with additional methods.

1. The parameter in the builder needs to be the extended builder, and not the type to be built.
2. All interfaces for the common parameters need to be parametrized with it to allow propper continuation.

Here is a suggestion:
1. Don't use `IName` interface. Replace it with static entry method of the builder
2. Parametrize `IAge` interface
3. No common builder needed. It can be replaced with inline lambda implementation

Here is the code:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface IAge<B> {
    B age(Integer age);
}

public class AnimalBuilder implements IBuild<Animal> {

    private final String name;
    private final Integer age;
    private Integer numberOfLegs;

    private AnimalBuilder(String name, Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // Builder entry method
    public static IAge<AnimalBuilder> name(String name) {
        return age -> new AnimalBuilder(name, age);
    }

    public AnimalBuilder numberOfLegs(int value) {
        numberOfLegs = value;
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Animal build() {
        return new Animal(name, age, numberOfLegs);
    }
}
```

This allows following usage:

```
AnimalBuilder.name("elvis").age(1).numberOfLegs(8).build();
```

Comment: thank you so much. I knew that I just missed some generic declaration and it was just bugging me all this time :) I'll paste my final code (the basic version, without lambdas) as an answer for the completeness sake

Answer (score 3):

Looks like to many generics in a code, I've tried to simplify it a little.

**Animal**

```
package come.stackoverflow.builder;

public abstract class Animal {
  private final String name; //mandatory field, one of many
  private final Integer age; //mandatory field, one of many

  Animal(final String name, final Integer age) {this.name = name; this.age = age;}

  public String getName() {return name;}
  public Integer getAge() {return age;}
  @Override public String toString() {return String.format("Animal {name='%s', age='%s'}'", name, age);}

  interface IBuild<T> {
    T build();
  }

  public abstract static class AnimalBuilder<B extends AnimalBuilder, T extends Animal> implements IBuild<T> {
    String name;
    Integer age;

    public B name(final String name) {this.name = name; return (B) this;}
    public B age(final Integer age) {this.age = age; return (B) this;}
  }
}
```

**Spider**

```
package come.stackoverflow.builder;

public class Spider extends Animal {
  private final Integer numberOfLegs; //optional field, one of many

  private Spider(final String name, final Integer age, final Integer numberOfLegs) {super(name, age); this.numberOfLegs = numberOfLegs;}

  public Integer getNumberOfLegs() {return numberOfLegs;}
  @Override public String toString() {return String.format("Spider {numberOfLegs='%s'}, %s", getNumberOfLegs(), super.toString());}

  public static class SpiderBuilder extends AnimalBuilder<SpiderBuilder, Spider> {
    Integer numberOfLegs;
    public SpiderBuilder numberOfLegs(final Integer numberOfLegs) {this.numberOfLegs = numberOfLegs; return this;}
    public Spider build() {return new Spider(name, age, numberOfLegs);}
  }
}
```

**Main Test**

```
import come.stackoverflow.builder.Spider;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Spider build = new Spider.SpiderBuilder()
            .name("elvis").numberOfLegs(8).age(1)
            .build();
        System.out.println(build);
    }
}
```

**Execution Result:**
  `Spider {numberOfLegs='8'}, Animal {name='elvis', age='1'}'`

Comment: hey. thanks for the comment, but i'm afraid that its not exacly what I need :) during the process this "fluent" part got lost. you can check out what I mean by that under http://blog.crisp.se/2013/10/09/perlundholm/another-builder-pattern-for-java

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the abstract builder :

```
public abstract static class Builder<T extends Animal<T>, B extends Builder<T, B>>
        implements IName, IAge, IBuild<T> {
 ...
    @Override
    public IAge name(String name) {
        objectBeingBuilt.name = name;
        return that();
    }

    @Override
    public IBuild age(Integer age) {
        objectBeingBuilt.age = age;
        return that();
    }
```

So, all your concrete builders return the same `IBuild<T>` interface when you invoke the `age()` method.

and as you see :

```
interface IBuild<T extends Animal<T>> {
    T build();
}
```

this interface doesn't allow to return a object where you have  methods to set properties with your builder.

When you invoke the `name()` method, you also don't get the builder :

```
interface IAge {
    IBuild age(Integer age);
}
```

You should declare `age()` and `name()` in the abstract builder like that :

```
public abstract static class Builder<T extends Animal<T>, B extends Builder<T, B>>{
   ...

    public B name(String name) {
        objectBeingBuilt.name = name;
        return that();
    }


    public B age(Integer age) {
        objectBeingBuilt.age = age;
        return that();
    }
```

In this way, at the compile time, the concrete builder will  return the builder of the animal you are creating when you will invoke`builder.age(..)`.
Besides, I don't understand why having a builder interface for name and another one for age.
 What is interest to handle `IAge` and `IName` interfaces ?
It seems a too low level information to be useful in your builder.
Why not simply declaring you base builder like that :

```
public abstract static class Builder<T extends Animal<T>, B extends Builder<T, B>>
            implements IBuild<T> {
        protected T objectBeingBuilt;

        protected abstract B that();
        protected abstract T createEmptyObject();

        Builder(){
            this.objectBeingBuilt = createEmptyObject();
            System.out.println();
        }

        public B name(String name) {
            objectBeingBuilt.name = name;
            return that();
        }

        public B age(Integer age) {
            objectBeingBuilt.age = age;
            return that();
        }

    }
```

I have not tested the code.

Comment: hey. thanks for the comment, but the whole problem I have is in building this **fluent** builder. in this case I want user to be restricted to using first name, then age and then others with no other way around it :)

Comment: No problem :) Personally, I find too restricting to fix the order of the method to use with. A client should be able to choose the order of the properties that one wants to populate. Which matters is that your build method does the check that the state is consistent before returning the object.